# How can this assembly homework be completed

Tags: assembly, mips

Question: Complete the following assembly code to calculate the value of the quotient and the remainder of the expression (ax2 - bx)/(cx + 1), where a, b, c are given and x will be your input from the keyboard?

Example:

```
input the value of x: 3

(a*x^2 - b*x)/(c*x + 1) = 1


remainder = 5
```

Solution:

```
.data

    a: .word 3

    b: .word 5

    c: .word 2

    prompt: .asciiz "input the value of x: "

    quotient: .asciiz "(a*x^2 - b*x)/(c*x + 1) = "

    remainder: .asciiz "remainder = "

.text

main:

    lw $t0, a

    lw $t1, b

    lw $t2, c

    li $t4, 1 # load the constant 1 from the expression (a*x^2 - b*x)/(c*x + 1) to the register $t4

    la $a0, prompt

    jal printString


        ...

        ...

        ...


printString:

    li $v0, 4

    syscall

    jr $ra

printInt:

    li $v0, 1

    syscall

    jr $ra

newLine:

    li $v0, 11

    ....

        ...

        ...
```

Comment: I voted to close this because it looks like a "please do my homework" request, as no attempt to program the given expression has been started.  However, I have provided an answer to the literal question how to approach this problem, just in cases.

Comment: Use a code block to format your code: enclose it with `\`\`\`` on a line by itself.  That makes the double spacing unnecessary.  I added the code block but perhaps you could go back and fix the double spacing which makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how to go about translating a complex expression into assembly language.

The basic approach is to decompose the problem into a set of simpler problems, then solve the simpler problems, then reassembly the solution to the simpler problems into an overall solution.

Let's start by looking at the concept of [three address code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-address_code).

Three address code breaks an expression into fundamental parts, so that we do one operation per line: one operation like addition or multiplication.

Instead of `a+b*c`, in TAC we have

```
t1 = b*c
t2 = a+t1
```

This decomposition of expressions requires the introduction of temporary variables, which interconnect the lines of TAC.

In assembly language we can substitute temporary variables with CPU registers.

---

Let's also note an approach called [Strength Reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction).

If we need to square something, most processors won't have that as an integer operation, so if we have TAC of:

```
t3 = x^2
```

we can reduce the strength of the arithmetic operation, knowing that one of the operands is a constant.

```
t3 = x*x
```

produces the same answer and so is equivalent to squaring.

Hardware like MIPS cannot do integer square but can do multiplication.

(Simpler hardware like LC-3 or MARIE cannot even do multiplication directly so even `2*x` can be reduced to `x+x` and then done on such simpler hardware.)